# A fancy man talking nonsense

Tags: story

One day I met a fancy man, and tried to talk to him:

> **ME :** Hello sir! How is your day?
>   **HIM:** Are you conversing with my person ?
>   **ME :** Yes I am, you seem like a very interesting person and I'd like to...
>   **HIM:** To my horror, I shall not authorize you to pursue in this course of action.
>   **ME :** Why not?
>   **HIM:** You will have to acquire a larger vessel.
>   **ME :** For what? I don't undestand...
>   **HIM:** Our dear language, oedipian fellow, are you able to converse in it?
>   **ME :** OK, now you're being rude... I think.
>   **HIM:** I reckon this is quite a large heap of excrement.
>   **ME :** I'm sorry, do you have a problem?
>   **HIM:** I witness individuals no longer breathing.
>   **ME :** I see...
>   **HIM:** Please greet my short acquaintance.
>   **ME :** There is no one else here. Or is this one of those "non-breathing people"?
>   **HIM:** I will bestow the man a proposal he won't be able to decline.
>   **ME :** He won't be able to accept it either, since he is inexistant.
>   **HIM:** You are unable to withstand the veracity.
>   **ME :** And can you tell me what is this "veracity"?
>   **HIM:** I relish the perfume of burning phosphorus at dawn.
>   **ME :** Well, now you're freaking me out. It was... nice to meet you sir, have a good day.
>   **HIM:** I shall wish the Strength to go along your person.
>   **ME :** Thank you, now go away from me.
>   **HIM:** I shall return promptly.
>   **ME :** Please don't.

**What the hell was this all about?**

Comment: This sounds like a friend of mine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All his replies are

> reworded film quotes

In particular:

> **HIM: Are you conversing with my person ?**
>  You talkin' to me? (Taxi Driver)
>
>  **HIM: To my horror, I shall not authorize you to pursue in this course of action.**
>  I'm afraid I can't [let you] do that. (2001 A Space Odyssey)
>  **Edit:** I have looked this one up now, because it didn't quite match. There's "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.", and a little later "I know that you and Frank were planning to disconnect me, and I'm afraid that's something I cannot allow to happen.". Neither matches exactly.
>
>  **HIM: You will have to acquire a larger vessel.**
>  You're gonna need a bigger boat. (Jaws)
>
>  **HIM: Our dear language, oedipian fellow, are you able to converse in it?**
>  English mofo, do you speak it? (Pulp Fiction)
>
>  **HIM: I reckon this is quite a large heap of excrement.**
>  That is one big pile of sh*t! (Jurassic Park, Thanks [ManyPinkHats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48964/manypinkhats))
>
>  **HIM: I witness individuals no longer breathing.**
>  I see dead people. (The Sixth Sense)
>
>  **HIM: Please greet my short acquaintance.**
>  Say hello to my little friend! (Scarface)
>
>  **HIM: I will bestow the man a proposal he won't be able to decline.**
>  I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse. (The Godfather)
>
>  **HIM: You are unable to withstand the veracity.**
>  You can't handle the truth! (A Few Good Men)
>
>  **HIM: I relish the perfume of burning phosphorus at dawn.**
>  I love the smell of napalm in the morning. (Apocalypse Now)
>
>  **HIM: I shall wish the Strength to go along your person.**
>  May the Force be with you. (Star Wars)
>
>  **HIM: I shall return promptly.**
>  I'll be back. (The Terminator)

Comment: Darn, too slow by a minute. Check my answer for the last one; I'll delete my answer in a bit

Comment: @ManyPinkHats Thanks for that one. I don't think I would have recognised that quote.

Comment: That was (expectedly) fast, good job!

Comment: @Keelhaul - Does the puzzle's title also refer to something? Or is it unrelated to the puzzle?

Comment: @Batman No, it just fits the story :)